# What does "AttributeError: 'X' object has no attribute 'y'" mean in Python?

Tags: python, attributeerror

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\konul\PycharmProjects\Assignment3\Konul_301082873_A3.py", line 11, in <module>
    class DrawData:
  File "C:\Users\konul\PycharmProjects\Assignment3\Konul_301082873_A3.py", line 47, in DrawData
    x, y = obj.generate_XY()
AttributeError: 'DrawData' object has no attribute 'generate_XY'
```

Comment: This simply means that the DrawData object herein, 'obj' has no attribute generate_XY(). Means you cannot use generate_XY() on that object type, your code has errors.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

The `DrawData` class was implemented without the attribute `generate_XY()`, so you cannot call that method from an instance of the class (`obj`).